# Is it possible to modify a graphql input model to reference an object using a composite key instead of id?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I have two models in my schema. 1) Tree - that uses ID as a primary key and 2) Attribute -that uses has a composite key. I would like to create a third table 3) TreeAttributes -  that will reference 1st and 2nd objects, but when mutating I would like to reference the second object with a composite key.

I couldn't find anything like this in aws or Graphql documentations. I'm wondering if this is even possible?

Current schema looks something like this:

```
type Tree @model {
  id: ID!
  address: String! 
  description: String
  attributes: [TreeAttributes] @connection (name: "treeAttributes")
}

type Attribute @model (subscriptions: null) @key(fields: ["name", "value"]) {
  name: String!
  value: [String]!
  description: String
  active: Boolean
  trees: [TreeAttributes] @connection (name: "attributeTrees")
  id: ID
}

type TreeAttributes @model(queries: null)  {
  id: ID!
  tree: Tree! @connection (name: "treeAttributes")
  attribute: Attribute! @connection (name: "attributeTrees")
}
```

Currently my input model looks like this:

```
input CreateTreeAttributesInput {
    treeAttributesTreeId: ID!
    treeAttributesAttributeId: ID!
}
```

but instead, i'd like it to look something like this:

```
input CreateTreeAttributesInput {
    treeAttributesTreeId: ID!
    treeAttributesAttribute: {
                                  name: String!
                                  value: String!}
}
```

Comment: This is certainly possible within GraphQL, but you may have to modify the VTL in the resolver of CreateTreeAttributes to construct the composite key.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this document to construct many-to-many relationship between your models.
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#field-level-authorization

It is recommended to use new definition of the @connection, you can specify keyName and fields for it.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because we cannot be sure how long the link will be available for, you should also include a summary from that article targets specifically for OP. So in this case, show us the code to specify _the connection and the keyName fields for it_